# innerHTML for <script> works in FF, not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to populate a `<select>` element via Ajax. It works great in FF, but I get an `unknown runtime error` in IE.

HTML:

```
<select id="emp_select" name="emp_select">
    <option value=" ">Please enter a store</option> 
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#store").blur(function() {
    populateDropdowns();
});

...

function populateDropdowns() {
        var store = $("#store").val();

        if (store.length != 4) {
            alert("Store # must be 4 digits!");
            $("#store").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var xhrJSON = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var xhrEmpSelect = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var xhrMgrSelect = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var jsonDone = false;
        var empSelectDone = false;
        var mgrSelectDone = false;

        $("#processing-dialog").dialog({
                width: 300,
                height: 150
        });

        xhrJSON.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhrJSON.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhrJSON.status == 200) {
                    var js = document.createElement('script');
                    js.type = 'text/javascript';

                    js.innerHTML = xhrJSON.responseText;
                    var scr = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1];
                    scr.parentNode.insertBefore(js,scr);

                    jsonDone = true;
                    if (jsonDone && empSelectDone && mgrSelectDone) {
                        $("#processing-dialog").dialog("close");
                        $("#processing-dialog").dialog("destroy");
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        xhrEmpSelect.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhrEmpSelect.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhrEmpSelect.status == 200) {
                    $("#emp_select").html(xhrEmpSelect.responseText);
                    empSelectDone = true;
                    if (jsonDone && empSelectDone && mgrSelectDone) {
                        $("#processing-dialog").dialog("close");
                        $("#processing-dialog").dialog("destroy");
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        xhrMgrSelect.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhrMgrSelect.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhrMgrSelect.status == 200) {
                    $("#mgr_select").html(xhrMgrSelect.responseText);
                    mgrSelectDone = true;
                    if (jsonDone && empSelectDone && mgrSelectDone) {
                        $("#processing-dialog").dialog("close");
                        $("#processing-dialog").dialog("destroy");
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        var url = "ajax.cgi";

        var JSONdata = "action=generateJSON&store=" + store;
        var EmpSelectData = "action=generateEmpSelect&store=" + store;
        var MgrSelectData = "action=generateMgrSelect&store=" + store;

        xhrJSON.open("POST",url);
        xhrJSON.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhrJSON.send(JSONdata);

        xhrEmpSelect.open("POST",url);
        xhrEmpSelect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhrEmpSelect.send(EmpSelectData);

        xhrMgrSelect.open("POST",url);
        xhrMgrSelect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhrMgrSelect.send(MgrSelectData);
    }
```

The `blur` handler calls a function to populate (all) the different select elements, plus a JavaScript object that holds an associative array of all the employees to match up a name with an employee id that is returned as the values of the options in both `select` elements.

XHR Text returned (for xhrJSON, content-type=application/json):

```
var empArray = new Array({ id:"12345678", title:"The Title", code:"C123", name:"John Doe"},...);
```

XHR Text returned for (xhrEmpSelect, content-type=text/html):

```
<option value=" ">Select One</option>
<option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
<option value="Joe Blow">Joe Blow</option>
...
<option value="other">Other...</option>
</select>
```

Similar text is returned for xhrMgrSelect, content-type=text/html

So in FF everything works great, the JS Object comes across and is inserted into the DOM and both `<select>` elements are populated as well. BUT in IE, I get an `unknown runtime error` in the `xhrJSON.onreadystatechange` handler where I try and set the `js.innerHTML` to the `xhrJSON.responseText`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yikes!  If you are using jQuery you should use the .Ajax routines -- make your life easy in these x-platform issues.

Comment: I've never had good luck with $.ajax (and never bothered to really troubleshoot it! I know, shame on me... :-(

Comment: it has nothing to do with *luck*

Comment: "Doctor it hurts when I do this."  "Don't do that"

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I agree! I already shamed myself, do you want a public flogging? ;-P

Comment: Title says `innerHTML` for `<select>`. Question shows `innerHTML` on a `<script>`. You probably meant `<script>` in the title?

Comment: @amnotiam You are correct, kind poster. I will edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `js.text = xhrJSON.responseText;` instead of `innerHTML`. I believe the issue you are encountering has to do with the fact that you can't insert HTML into a `<script>` block.

Comment: This was the clear winner. `innerText` and `textContent` did not work for me. Neither did `setText(text)`. Thanks @pseudosavant!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the script you should use `innerText` instead of innerHTML. Try this.

```
js.innerText = xhrJSON.responseText;
//Since FF do not sussport innerText but it does support textContent
js.textContent = xhrJSON.responseText;
```

I would advice you to migrate your code to jQuery which will be much simpler, readable, and easy to maintain without any worries of cross browser support. jQuery does everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

To set the contents of a [HTMLScriptElement](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/html2/HTMLScriptElement.html) object, (created using `document.createElement('script');`) you should use the `setText` method of the object instead of trying to set the `innerHTML` of the script.

```
js.setText(xhrJSON.responseText);
```

See the W3 specification from the link above.